# Обновление системных кистей (стилей) на лету в Windown Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, style, winrt

Необходимо обновить цвет системных элементов на лету, т.е. такие как цвет переключателя, цвет выделения листбокса, и подобное. Я нашёл системные кисти, которыми, прописав в app.xaml, в ресурсах, я изменил цвет (при загрузке приложения), но изменение этих кистей из кода c# на лету не даёт должного эффекта. Как можно перезагрузить стили/обновить элементы?

Мне нужно нечто подобное как в стандартном почтовом клиенте, там в настройках можно сменить цвет фона, и соответственно там меняются и цвета элементов, мгновенно.

Вот как я пытался это сделать:

App.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MainBrush">#FF009999</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Value="50"/>
        <ListBox SelectedIndex="1" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="TEXT"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="TEXT"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="TEXT"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ToggleSwitch IsOn="True"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="10" Margin="0,20" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <Rectangle Height="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="RectBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MainBrush}"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,60,0,0" Content="ИЗМЕНИТЬ ЦВЕТ ВСЕГО ЭТОГО"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var c = Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 0, 200);
    RectBrush.Color = c; // прямой способ, естественно работает
    Application.Current.Resources["MainBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush"] = c;
    Application.Current.Resources["SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush"] = c;
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, как именно такое делается в WP8. В WPF это делается так: контролы ссылаются на нужные `Brush`'и (не `Color`'ы!) наподобие [`ActiveBorderBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.activeborderbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и обязательно как `DynamicResource`. Поскольку `Color` в `SolidColorBrush` не является `DependencyProperty`, то обновление системного ресурса не приведёт к обновлению `Brush`'а (но это снова-таки опыт WPF, не WP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThemeResource` работает как `StaticResource`, а не как `DynamicResource`, то есть значение не перевычисляется, если значение в словаре поменяется. И уж конечно, не отлавливаются изменения свойств объектов в словаре.

`ThemeResource` предполагает, что ресурсы располагаются не в корне `Application.Resources`, а в отдельных словарях ресурсов `ThemeDictionaries`. Во всех темах набор ключей должен быть идентичен. На данный момент поддерживаются две темы: Light, Dark, а также вариации HighContrast. При изменении `Application.RequestedTheme` значения, полученные от `ThemeResource`, будут перевычислены. См. [ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968442.aspx) ([ResourceDictionary и ссылки на ресурсы XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968442.aspx)).

Аналог `DynamicResource` в WinRT-XAML отсутствует. У вас два пути:

1. Завести глобальную вью-модель со свойством типа `SolidColorBrush AccentColorBrush` и во вью биндиться к ней. Биндинги отработают при изменении свойства, и цвета изменятся.
2. Требовать перезагрузки приложения; при загрузке задавать цвет, выбранный пользователем.

Учтите, что первый способ может сказаться на производительности, если у вас сложные вьюхи.

Comment: Нету `DynamicResource`? Печаль. Но хоть планируют может, не знаете?

Comment: @VladD Понятия не имею. Думаю, разрабы решили, что DR — это слишком медленно. Это как бы не самая большая потеря, в WinRT вообще всё урезанное и выпиленное.

Comment: У меня весь код на DR :( Ладно, останусь пока на десктопе :)

Comment: Athari, благодарю за подробное разъяснение проблемы, а можно пример простенький для первого пункта?)

Comment: @Олег С VM что ли? В чём именно проблема?

Comment: @Athari, да с vm, не приходилось пользоваться ещё, начинающий прогер)

Comment: @Олег Советую для начала почитать про MVVM. Копипаста готового решения вам только помешает разобраться.

Comment: @Athari, так я и не нашел времени почитать про mvvm, вчера вечером пришла идея как сделать, взял шаблоны элементов нужных вставил в майнпейдж и там нужные кисти заменил биндингом от другого элемента, у которого нормально меняется. Всё прекрасно работает, интерфейс меняется под цвет обложки),  можете посмотреть результат, если инетересно, DM Player, в магазине, тени под шрифт только добавлю и норм будет.